# Как удалить последние коммиты в sourcetree?

Tags: git, git-commit, source-tree

Разбирался в программе, пока не натворил делов в локальном репозитории. Как мне удалить эти последние 2 коммита?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Удалить - вернуть как было до них. Или удалить - чтоб их не было в истории?

Comment: удалить - чтобы в истории их не было, никаких файлов не осталось

Answer (score 0):

Можете использовать команду `git reset --hard <коммит>` либо просто удалить локальный мастер и создать его заново)

[Инструменты Git - Раскрытие тайн reset](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD-reset)